# can i put if in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table Client that contain column ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn in My SQL server 2008 R2.
In my C# code i have 4 Combobox that choose the value ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn.

the value Combobox Client:

```
-- all
-- 457896
-- 85446
-- etc
```

the value or Departement:

```
-- all
-- 44
-- 85
-- etc
```

the same also tourne

the value of Hour:

```
-- all
-- 09:00
-- 12:00
-- 15:00
-- 18:00
```

there are 4 value that mean lot of combination. When my math is good there are 16 combination.
of course i can write 16 SQL syntax.

1. SQL when the user choose All for 4 combobox

SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn
FROM Client

2. SQL when the user choose Client X, all for 3 other combobox

SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn
FROM Client
WHERE ClientID = x

3. SQL when the user choose Client X and Dept Y, and all for 2 other combobox

   SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn
   FROM Client
   WHERE ClientID = x 
   ANd Departement = Y

and until 16 SQL. in C# code i use switch that select SQL syntax that corespondent with my 4 combobox selector.

i wonder if i can put 16 sql syntax in 1 sql, something like this:

```
SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn
FROM Client
WHERE -- if @ClientID is not null then ClientID = @ClientID else not use clientid citere
AND Tourn= @LIB_TOURNE -- same as above
AND -- same as above(substring(Departement,0,3) IN (SELECT ParsedString From dbo.ParseStringList(@Departement)))
AND -- same as abovedatepart(hh, Hour) <=12
```

i am not good enoungh in SQL, any idea ?

that mean when the user select client = ALL then i don't need WHERE ClientID = X,
that mean when the user select Departement = ALL then i don't need WHERE Departement = y
and so on

Comment: like you do or make a linq variant (with EF or another OR Mapper)

Comment: When you say "same as above", do you mean that client must be evaluated for NULL?

Answer (score 3):

Use COALESCE function

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190349.aspx

```
    SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn
    FROM Client
    WHERE ClientID =COALESCE (@ClientID, ClientID)
```

COALESCE is like that:

```
ClientID =COALESCE (@ClientID, ClientID)
```

means:

```
ClientID =
case when @ClientID is null then ClientID
else @ClientID
```

Hence, if @ClientID is null, the filter is ClientID=ClientID, which means it will match by default

Comment: Not sure how this performs, but this looks neat.

Comment: Werner, I have given more info in the answer

Comment: I just checked on a table with 388000 rows: these five select * from t perform equally fast: no where-clause, where 1=1, where id=id, where id=coalesce(\@id,id), where id=case when \@id is null then id else \@id end. Seems like there is no need to adjust the SQL depending on if some parameters are given or not.

Answer (score 1):

What is so bad about this solution? You only need to handle 4 cases, not 16!?

```
string strSQL = "SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn FROM Client WHERE 1=1";
if(first_checkbox) {
    strSQL += " AND ClientID=@ClientID";
    add value for parameter @ClientID;
}
if(second_checkbox) {
    strSQL += " AND Departement=@Departement";
    add value for parameter @Departement;
}
...
```

Of course you can get rid of the "1=1" if you keep track if the current condition is the first to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn
FROM Client
WHERE 
  (@ClientID = ClientID or @ClientID is null)
  and ( another condition in the same manner)
  and ( another condition in the same manner)
  and ( another condition in the same manner)
```

assuming you're passing null to appropriate parameter's value when 'All' selected in combobox

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn
FROM Client
WHERE  (( @CLientID is null ) OR (( @ClientID is not null ) and ( @ClientId = ClientId))) 
AND    (( @Department is null ) OR (( @Department is not null ) and ( @Department = Department))) 
AND    (( @Hour is null ) OR (( @Hour is not null ) and ( @Hour = Hour))) 
AND    (( @Tourn is null ) OR (( @Tourn is not null ) and ( @Tourn = Tourn)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT ClientID, Departement, Hour, Tourn
FROM Client
WHERE 
1 = CASE 
WHEN @ClientID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CASE 
        WHEN ClientID = @ClientID
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
    ELSE 1
END
AND 1 = CASE 
    WHEN @LIB_TOURNE IS NOT NULL
    THEN CASE 
        WHEN Tourn= @LIB_TOURNE
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
    ELSE 1
END
AND -- same as abovedatepart(hh, Hour) <=12
```